# How to send immediately headers

Tags: nginx, php, output-buffering

```
<?php
header("X-Accel-Buffering: no");
header('Content-Encoding: none;');
//and yet other headers

ob_end_flush();
flush();
sleep(1);

echo time().PHP_EOL;
flush();
sleep(2);
echo time().PHP_EOL;
```

So, when I use Apache + php, and turn off buffering in Apache and php,
and get a page of this scipt, I will see in firebug, that the time of waiting response is about 0(localhost used)

but, if the same way with nginx with php-fpm, I will see, that the time of waiting response is about 1second.

So, nginx (or php-fpm) doesn't want to send headers immediately. Why?
how can I do my task?

PS
according different forums

nginx conf - 
    proxy_buffering off;
    fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 0;
    fastcgi_keep_conn on;
    gzip off;

php conf
    output_buffering = Off

Comment: We see you tagged nginx but you've stated Apache several times. Please clarify your question, is this about Apache or Nginx?

Comment: Nginx!!(apache like example, what works. but nginx doesn't work as I want, so question about nginx)

Answer (score 0):

The `X-Accel-Buffering: no` header does not affect `fastcgi_buffering` until **>= nginx-1.5.6**. This is likely the cause of your problems, because the default fastcgi buffers are 4-8k, and are utilized in an nginx+php-fpm setup.